# Flow Error message: Unable to process the email template...Argument cannot be null

Tags: visual-workflow, email-template, email-alert, sales-cloud, debug

Can anyone help with this Flow error message:
Error Occurred:

We were unable to process the email template. **Error Message: core.email.template.TemplateRenderingException: Argument cannot be null.**

It is a record-triggered flow with emails once Opportunities are moved to the closed won - there is a decision element on which country the Opportunity is being closed for (based on Account Site) so it sends email with the 'Email Alert' element, to relevant stakeholders. It is working as expected for other Opportunities which are also using the same Visualforce email template but with just 1 specific country it is throwing the error.

Comment: This needs more detail - specifically, what kind of email template; the flow element that is used for the email action (screenshot).

Comment: Hi Cropredy, thanks for commenting, I have updated my question

Comment: OK, we need to see the Email Alert and corresponding email template. Email alerts need a target object Id. If the corresponding email template is a VF email template, then the recipientId and relatedToId must be non-null and if VF components are used, there are other possible required fields